# Is it possible to prevent Google Web Light from removing multipart attributes from form tag?

Tags: forms, file-upload, multipartform-data, googleweblight

I have a form that contains a file input and the form is configured correctly to handle this normally. The form tag contains the following attribute:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

This works fine in all normal browsers, but not in Google Web Light. In Google Web Light I noticed that the file name is being passed, but not the associated file data.

Upon inspection of the page as modified through Google Web Light I noticed the enctype attribute was removed and I believe this is the issue with why the file data is not getting passed the form's action.

Is there any way to prevent Google Web Light from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also looking for a way of having Google Web Light preserve:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

As a workaround, have you tried 'Opting out of transcoding' from https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en ?

> If you do not want your pages to be transcoded, set the HTTP header "Cache-Control: no-transform" in your page response. If Googlebot sees this header, your page will not be transcoded.

Comment: This was the solution we used as well. I couldn't really find anything else on controlling how the page was transformed to keep important pieces like this intact. A less efficient page with all of the functionality seemed better than a more efficient broken page!